# Quicktime Plugin 7.6.6 shows up in my firefox, but not for other users

Tags: macos, firefox-extensions, quicktime

If I log in with my admin account and open firefox > plugins, I see the Quicktime extension installed.  But I do not see this extension installed if I log in with a non-admin account on the same machine.  Is it possible to install this for all users?

Other extensions show up, just not quicktime.  The plugin is installed in /Library/Internet-plugins.  The permissions on the file conform to the permissions/owner of the other plugins.

Mac OS 10.6.8, Firefox 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the default user profile for the machine was missing the com.apple.quicktime.plugin.preferences.plist file which sets mime types.

Copying this plist to /System/Library/User Template/ English.lproj/Library/Preferences enabled new users to get the plist, which fixed the problem.